# CSS/JavaScript: Make element top-most z-index/top-most modal element

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index, modal-dialog

I would like to make an element (e.g. a `<div>`) be the top-most layer on the page.

My assumption is that the only way I can do this is to specify that the element has a `style="z-index:"` value that is the maximum the browser allows (int32?).

Is this correct?

Instead, would it be possible to somehow get the element's `z-index` whose is highest, and make this `<div>`'s `z-index` the `[highest element's value] + 1`? For example:

```
$myDiv.css("z-index", $(document.body).highestZIndex() + 1);
```

How do modal JavaScript "windows" work?

Comment: firefox highest z-index is 2147483647   just to mention.

Answer (score 8):

Here's how to do it :

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
var highest_index = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length - 1; i++) {
    if (parseInt(elements[i].style.zIndex) > highest_index) {
        highest_index = parseInt(elements[i].style.zIndex;
    }
}
```

highest_index now contains the highest z-index on the page... just add 1 to that value and apply it wherever you want. You can apply it like so :

```
your_element.style.zIndex = highest_index + 1;
```

Here's another way of achieving the same thing using jQuery :

```
var highest_index = 0;

$("[z-index]").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("z-index") > highest_index) {
         highest_index = $(this).attr("z-index");
    }
});
```

Again, same way to apply the new index to an element :

```
$("your_element").attr("z-index", highest_index + 1);
```

Comment: `i < elements.length - 1`?

Comment: Make sure to use `.css`, not `.attr`!

Comment: Note that this algorithm is very expensive and may dramatically slow down your client UI performance if you're going to execute this code frequently.

Comment: what happens when there is an element with z-index of '2147483647' ? (biggest firefox z-index available.

Answer (score 3):

What about stacking context? It is **not** always true that: On a document highest z-index will be on top. See: http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/. If you do not take stacking context into account, setting a billion may not be enough to make your element on the top-most.

Answer (score 1):

http://abcoder.com/javascript/a-better-process-to-find-maximum-z-index-within-a-page/ -> find the max z-index and assign +1 to it.

Answer (score 1):

Sheavi's jQuery solution doesn't work because z-index is a css style, not an attribute.

Try this instead:

```
raiseToHighestZindex = function(elem) {
    var highest_index = 0;
    $("*").each(function() {
        var cur_zindex= $(this).css("z-index");
        if (cur_zindex > highest_index) {
            highest_index = cur_zindex;
            $(elem).css("z-index", cur_zindex + 1);
        }
    });
    return highest_index;
};
```

Return value may not be what you expect due to Javascript's async nature, but calling the function on any element will work fine.

Comment: `"Return value may not be what you expect due to Javascript's async nature"` The only asynchronous function I know were: `setInterval`, `setTimeout`, and `AJAX`