# Stacked divs need active z-index hover state

Tags: html, css, hover, z-index

If you look at my page [located here](http://roseannebarr.tumblr.com/) you can see the stacked divs. They are floated to the left and have a negative right margin. Whe you hover over them they are given a z-index of 100 bringing them to the top of the stack. However, when you go from left to right you notice that the one that had began the stack is still right behind the hovered one, so the one you had hovered over previously falls behind the stack, making it's right or left column invisible.

My idea to solve this was to give each "active" card a z-index of 99 while having the cards in their normal state z-index 98. However, it's not working :-(

Do you have any ideas to solve my dilemma?

```
.card {
margin-right:-670px;
float:left;
width:700px;
height:500px;
background:#EEE;
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #000;
position:relative;
z-index:98;
}

.card:visited {
z-index:99;
}

.card:hover {
z-index:100;
}
```

Edit:

This is what my end product will look like. Thank you for the suggestions, but they aren't quite answers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You realize that "active" translates to "is currently being clicked", Right?

I don't see how there's anyway to accomplish what you want without jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You might have better success with a different approach.

Have your cards fit as background within thin div's as you already do, but also have full card visibility:hidden at same position.  You mouse over card edge and change the visibility to show for the associated full card.  Mouse off and visibility goes hidden again.

trying to stack them keeping them all visible, etc is begging for trouble :)

Comment: The reason is they are posted dynamically, it's a theme for Tumblr. This means I can't account for separate cards. Also in an audio post, if it is not visible the audio quits playing on the post and who wants to sit on the same post for 3-4+ minutes? Plus

Comment: Ok then try stacking them z-index sequentially: 99, 100, 101, etc.  Make the one selected higher than the rest.  You'll just need to maintain the original z-index order.  [Finding the topmost z-index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755631/css-javascript-make-element-top-most-z-index-top-most-modal-element) can help in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://www.w3avenue.com/2010/04/05/cross-browser-pure-css3-horizontal-accordion/) for a js free way of achieveing what you want. I agree with zagnut about using the images as a background to your divs look at [this](http://www.killersites.com/mvnforum/mvnforum/viewthread_thread,6459) for a way to achieve that. I would also recomend a general cleanup of your html

Comment: Thankyou! I know I'm a mess. :(

Comment: The demo is nice but defeats the purpose of my design :(